# Cucumber test case not running via Spring Boot Jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, cucumber

When I am running my Spring boot Application via Eclipse I am able to execute my cucumber test(Main.run(requestParamter, contextClassLoader)) case but when I am running via Spring boot Jar I'm getting below exception.

Test cases could not execute successfully and exception is:

```
 io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: The resource
 jar:file:/C:/386619/iplus-qeas-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar!/
 is located in a nested jar.\n\nThis typically happens when trying to
 run Cucumber inside a Spring Boot Executable Jar.\nCucumber currently
 doesn't support classpath scanning in nested jars.\nFeel free to send
 a pull request to make this possible!\n\nYou can avoid this error by
 unpacking your application before executing.
```

Comment: Spring Boot often uses a plugin that packs your application with all its dependencies in the jar, instead of just your application itself as is normal.  This makes it runnable, but means that jars are now _inside_ the jar, which Cucumber currently cannot scan.

Answer (score 1):

You are running Cucumber from inside an executable jar file. This means that if you open the jar file you'll see something like this:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-executable-jar-format.html

```
example.jar
 |
 +-META-INF
 |  +-MANIFEST.MF
 +-org
 |  +-springframework
 |     +-boot
 |        +-loader
 |           +-<spring boot loader classes>
 +-BOOT-INF
    +-classes
    |  +-mycompany
    |     +-project
    |        +-YourClasses.class
    +-lib
       +-dependency1.jar
       +-dependency2.jar
```

Right now cucumber is scanning the entire class path for glue and feature files. This includes your dependencies in `BOOT-INF/lib`. However Cucumber can't open these. Cucumber can however read the contents of `BOOT-INF/classes` because that is mostly like a normal jar file.

So try passing `--glue mycompany.project --features:classpath:mycompany/project`. This way Cucumber will only scan the contents of`BOOT-INF/classes`.